One-hot encoding for value - multivalue scaling?
I am working through some introductory material on formal concept analysis, and came across discussion of what I am familiar with as "one hot encoding", but for prices as value.
So with one-hot encoding, one could break down screen size into 13", 14" 15" and just code hot the appropriate value. However for price as value, say the values <$1000, <$1500, <$2000, <$2500, would each have those above them in the hierarchy all coded as hot. So, if something is less than 1500, it is also less than 2000 and 2500, and would have therefore all those marked in one-hot.
Is there a term for this specific type of usage of one-hot encoding? I would like to investigate this further, but the term "multivalue scaling", that was used in the discussion/context of formal concept analysis, and its variants didn't seem to pull anything in SE, and one-hot encoding with integers or values, just pulls a mess. Just knowing a proper term for this would be useful in digging a little deeper.
Cheers!

Do you also have the specific price in your dataset in addiction to these bins? When data has discrete values that have an order/hierarchy to them, that data is referred to as ordinal.

No, we don't have both the ordinal and the "one-hot" bins. The bins that I am calling "one-hot" here substitute for the ordinal values, and are coded "one-hot" to capture the full hierarchy in order to capture the fact that this value and" all of the above" all apply.

Ah, I was referring to your current labels of "<1000", "<1500", etc. as "ordinal", since there could be a hierarchy/order to them. The prices themselves ($950, $1245, etc.) are continuous. Not sure there's a specific term, other than potentially "ordinal encoding", but you could try "one-hot encoding" with conditions/criteria. Regardless, you could write a function to do this encoding manually.
